# Horizontal slider using fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I tried to create a full page horizontal slider by using [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) plugin. I use only one section with 3 slides.

I tried to add a fixed navigation to slides in the top of page, so user can open the slides directly from the top navigation, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me how to make it works?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="#" class="toSlide" data-index="1">Link to slide 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="toSlide" data-index="2">Link to slide 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="toSlide" data-index="3">Link to slide 3</a>
<div>
<div class="section" id="section0">
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">
        <h1>Slide 1.js</h1>
       This is slide 1
    </div>

    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        this is slide 2
    </div>

    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide3">
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$.fn.fullpage();
```

CSS

```
body{
    color: #fff;
}
h1{
    font-size:3em;
}
.section {
    text-align: center;
}

#section0{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top left, bottom left, from(#4bbfc3), to(#7baabe));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4BBFC3, #7BAABE);
    background: linear-gradient(#4BBFC3,#7BAABE);
}
#header{
        position:fixed;
        height: 50px;
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        background: #333;
        z-index:9;
        text-align:center;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    }

    #header{
        top:0px;
    }
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ksgn/)

Thank you!

Comment: unable to understand what is your question ?

Comment: I have improved the question. Thanks!

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical term. What doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the last version of the plugin (2.0.7) and use the new HTML markup which uses a wrapper for the plugin:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

Then initialize it this way:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage();
```

And then to create a fixed element just put it outside the plugin wrapper like you can see in this [live example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/fixedHeaders.html) sourcecode.

In order to create the links, don't use `toSlide`, use a normal URL link in case you are using anchors. (such as /#section/slide, for example: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage/2)

If you don't want to update your fullpage version for whatever reason, just use the option `fixedElements` as detailed in the documentation.

Comment: Hi alvaro, Thanks for your reply. I have updated the code as your instructions but the slide now isn't work. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/7ksgn/1/

Comment: I just found how to make it works. Thanks for the clue alvaro.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is looking to do this, I'll share how I got it done. I used the built in horizontal navigation dots. Set option to "top". I used the jQuery text() method to add the text I wanted to the nav dot anchors. The anchors get a class of active when the corresponding slide is being displayed already. From there just add your custom CSS to get them to look like you want and you end up with a menu that looks just like the vertical one but works with the slider.

Answer (score 1):

I know the topic is already 2 years old yet I faced the very same problem today and stumbled upon this article. Now that I´ve found a solution I thought it would be nice to share it with you guys!

```
<div class="wrap">
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="nav__item active" href="#firstPage/slide1">1</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__item" href="#firstPage/slide2">2</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__item" href="#firstPage/slide3">3</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__item" href="#firstPage/slide4">4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
      <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2"></div>
      <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide3"></div>
      <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Don´t forget to give the active class to the first anchor.

Note that if you want to set position:fixed; on the navigation outside you probably want to adjust your z-index (I set the z-index:1000; for the the wrap but do as you like)

And for .js I just used what already comes along with the FullPage.js

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage'],
    afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
      $('.nav__item.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.nav__item').eq(slideIndex).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Now our navigation anchors have an active class depending on the current slide
though I´m not sure if the href targets are best practise yet it works.

Of course you could just initalize the FullPage given navigation but this gives you full control over the markup.