# fullpage.js horizontal slider dots with tooltips

Tags: jquery, carousel, slideshow, fullpage.js

I'm playing around with fullpage.js and would like to use the built-in horizontal slider which works like a charm. What I am missing is the possibility to show a tooltip on each active dot (and when hovering them) as it does on the vertical section menu.

I found a brief guide to realize this feature in following question, comment from jfoutch at the very end: [horizontal slider using full page.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427425/horizontal-slider-using-fullpage-js/36204756#36204756). I don't know how to use the jQuery.text() method or rather where to start exactly.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution to realize tooltips on the horizontal slider dots! :)

I'm using the Bootstrap tooltip.js plugin (as I already use this framework for the grid system) and created the slider navigation by hand to set data-toogle and title for the tooltips:

```
<div class="fp-slidesNav bottom">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="fp-slide-dots" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Slide 1"><span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="fp-slide-dots" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Slide 2"><span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="fp-slide-dots" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Slide 3"><span></span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Next you have to initialize the tooltips:

```
$('.fp-slide-dots').tooltip();
```

It works! :)

Answer (score 1):

fullpage.js doesn't provide a way to do it as you can see in [this open issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/176).

What you can do is create your own navigation by using the methods fullpage.js uses, such as `moveTo` and activate or desactivate each nav bullet by using callbacks such as `afterLoad` or even the state class `fp-viewing-X-Y`that fullpagejs provides.

Comment: Could you please provide more information on how to deactivate each nav bullet of the horizontal slider?

Comment: Just add or remove the  `active` class en each `fp-nav a` elements.